# What connection should I enter for USB printer? (HPLIP)

Tags: debian, cups, printer

I am trying to add a HP LaserJet 1320N printer to CUPS. The printer is connected by USB. in the CUPS web admin interface, I selected `HPLIP`, then on the next page I have to enter `Connection`. According to [HPLIP documentation](http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/install/step4/cups/local.html) for connection by USB: *You MUST make a selection from the drop down that appears such as "hp:/usb/hp_deskjet_5600?serial=MY31R1K02179".*

However there is no dropdown, only a freeform text entry field. So I made a guess and entered `hp:/usb/laserjet`, but communication with the printer doesn't work.

*What should I enter for `Connection`?*

I am running Debian 3.2 with the Lynx text browser on the command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By looking at `/etc/cups/printers.conf`, I found out that *connection* refers to `DeviceURI`. HPLIP provides a tool to obtain that:

1. Connect printer by USB.
2. Get bus and device ID:

   ```
   $ lsusb
   [...]
   Bus 003 Device 005: ID 03f0:1d17 Hewlett-Packard LaserJet 1320
   ```
3. Get URI:

   ```
   $ hp-mkuri -b 003 -d 005
   hp:/usb/hp_LaserJet_1320_series?serial=00CNHW69TGWQ
   [...]
   ```